# Can PHP grab its own full output and process it?

Tags: php, output, output-buffering

I've already made a function which takes an input string representing a HTML document and validates it locally.

I'm trying to auto-validate my own PHP-generated webpages with it.

Can PHP store its own full output in a `$string` so that it can send this to my validator function in the very end, after all output is done?

Answer (score 1):

Yup!

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-contents.php

Basically:

```
<?php

ob_start();

echo "Hello ";

$out1 = ob_get_contents();

echo "World";

$out2 = ob_get_contents();

ob_end_clean();

var_dump($out1, $out2);
?>
```

Comment: What if some part of my code uses `ob_start()` etc. for other things? Can they be "wrapped"?

Comment: you mean nested?